# How to make an html form start a function

Tags: javascript, forms, textinput

I'm wondering if there is an easy way to make a form button with text input start a form that will check if the answer's correct and then proceed to tell you. Here's what I have, can you tell me what I need?

```
<!doctype html>
<body>
 <center>
  <form name="Input" action="Answer" method="get">
   <input type="text" name="Input">
   <input type="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   var A = Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
   var B = Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
   var C = A+B;
   var Input = document.getElementById('Input');
   document.write(A + "+" + B)
   function Answer()
   {
     alert("correct!!");
   }
 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does Input have to do with the correct answer?  Just wondering.

Comment: The input is part of the IF ELSE part that I took out of the code for this, sorry. It checks using if(input=C) { alert("correct!!");

Comment: _Ah._  That helps a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function calculateAnswer()
{
var A = Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
var B = Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
var C = A+B;
var Input = document.getElementById('Input');
if(Input.value == C)
{
document.body.innerHTML += (A + "+" + B);
//  Or another thing to do if the answer's correct
}
}
```

Also, attach an event listener to the submit button to make it run the function:

```
referenceToTheSubmitButton.addEventListener("click", calculateAnswer);
```

Indent as needed.
Enjoy!  :D

Comment: do I need to change the "referencetothesubmitbutton" part to something?

Comment: Yes.  You need to change it to a reference to the submit button, like `document.getElementById(submitId)`.  Also, you should change `name="Input"` to `id="Input"`, and add an ID to the submit button.

Comment: thanks! although the document.write isn't working, I need it to display beforehand to be able to see the variables I need to calculate the answer for. also, the submit button attempts to send me to a different page instead of just activating the function.  :P

Comment: Very welcome.  If you need to get the variables beforehand, initialize them before the function and then do what you like with them.  If I solved your problem, would you mind marking my answer as accepted by clicking the outline of the check mark?  Thanks!

Comment: and the text isn't showing up no matter where I put this:  document.write(A + "+" + B); P.S, thanks for putting up with my nooblieness!

Comment: @Trevader24135, we all have our moments of nobblieness.  I once spent 20 minutes on a stylesheet figuring out why it wouldn't load when I realized rel="stylesheet" was rel="stylsheet".  And instead of document.write, try `document.body.innerHTML += 'string'`.

Answer (score 0):

I know you aren't using jQuery, but are you looking for something of this [nature](http://jsfiddle.net/Luxelin/z528x/4/)?

It can easily be changed to plain javascript. I just wanted to use [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) for the easy visual effect of the alerts.

The html would be something along these lines (with jQuery and bootstrap):

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" id="correct">Your answer is currently 
    <span id="type"> INCORRECT </span>
</div>
<form>
    <input name="answer" id="answer">
</form>
<p>Hint: the answer is "correct"</p>
```

and the script would work like this:

```
$("#answer").keyup(function(){
if($(this).val() === "correct"){
    $("#correct").removeClass("alert-danger")
    .addClass("alert-success");
    $("#type").text("CORRECT!")
}
else{
    $("#correct").removeClass("alert-success")
    .addClass("alert-danger");
    $("#type").text("INCORRECT!")
}
}).keyup();
```

This is just a basic implementation of an input that checks for an answer. In this case, typing "correct" makes the alert green.