# Why is my code only displaying incorrect even if I have the right answer?

Tags: javascript, forms, function, math, button

I'm making a quick program to just teach myself the basics of functions, and everything works except for the IF ELSE statement. It always displays Incorrect, even if I use the right answer. Do I have to somehow use the key value for the number instead of the actual number?

```
<!doctype html>
<body>
<center>
<form Id="Input">
<input type="text" name="Input">
<input type="button" value="submit" ID="Button">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
Button.addEventListener("click", Answer);
var A = Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
var B = Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
var C = A +B;
var Input = document.getElementById('Input');
document.write(A + "+" + B + "=");
function Answer()
{
    if(Input.value == C)
    {
        alert("correct!");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("incorrect!");
    }
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A continuation from your other question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22213632/how-to-make-an-html-form-start-a-function

Comment: kind of, It's a different problem though.

Comment: Should try to keep it in the same question then, if it's regarding the same chunk-o-code

Answer (score 2):

`Input` is the id of the form element, you need to get the text element, so access the form via its id `Input` then the input element using its name so `Input.Input` then its value

```
function Answer() {
    if (Input.Input.value == C) {
        alert("correct!");
    } else {
        alert("incorrect!");
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gbXYL/)

---

Another way is to change the id of the form and assign the id `Input` to the text field like

```
<form Id="MyForm">
    <input type="text" name="Input" id="Input">
    <input type="button" value="submit" ID="Button">
</form>
```

then

```
function Answer() {
    if (Input.value == C) {
        alert("correct!");
    } else {
        alert("incorrect!");
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/S3Kjm/)

Comment: Thanks! This one worked so easy! can you explain why this works for me? It completely fixed it!

Comment: @user3385983 see the description above... when you said `Input.value` it was trying to access the `value` attribute of the `form` element, which is undefined

Comment: Thanks! That might help me remember some of this stuff for use in the future!